# Find a widget in a window by coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, label, coordinates

I make a window with tkinter and I want to check if a Label is at the coordinates relx = 0.3 and rely = 0.63. Is there any function which I could use?
I already tried to use the `nametowidget` function, but there I have to give every widget I have a name.

So, the widget I try to get is moving in the window and if it reaches the coordinates I want to move it in another way, but I dont know any function which I could use

Answer (score 0):

You can use `winfo_x/y` to get the label coordinates and `winfo_width/height` to get the dimension of the window to compute relative coordinates. I made a little example where the goal is to resize the window to get the right relative coordinates:

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_label_relpos():
    relx = l.winfo_x()/parent.winfo_width()
    rely = l.winfo_y()/parent.winfo_height()

    if (abs(relx - 0.3) < 0.02) and (abs(rely - 0.63) < 0.02):
        print("Ok")
    else:
        print(relx, rely, "Try again")

parent = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(parent, text="Label text", bg="red")
l.place(x=50, y=160)

tk.Button(parent, text="Check label relpos", command=check_label_relpos).place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor="s")

parent.mainloop()
```